# How to upgrade the client?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, runtime-upgrade

I want to do a runtime upgrade but I got the same error as [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/runtime-upgrade-error-host-doesnt-provide-such-function-envext-storage-root)

**solution is :- If there are changes not only to the runtime but also to the node, then this issue is normally caused by upgrading the runtime before upgrading the client.**

**Try upgrading the client, then the runtime.**

but i don't know how to upgrade the client? How can i upgrade the client?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link you shared, you want to upgrade your node to a newer substrate version. If the newer substrate version only requires changes in the runtime, you can do a runtime upgrade "on-chain" (it is not required to shut down the node). However, if the newer substrate version requires changes on the client side , you need to do a client upgrade.

You can upgrade the client by stopping the node, compile the new code (`cargo build --release`) and run the new binary (`./target/...`).

And to give an example for the error. When there is a new host function in the client which did not exist yet in an older client version, and the upgraded runtime uses this new host function. You need to upgrade the client otherwise you'll get such an error.

Comment: How can i upgrade my client?

Comment: @WakarSerajKhan see updated answer. Please say if something is still unclear to you

Comment: I am using substrate version 0.9.17 which is build on substrate 1.63.0 and using another old substrate version which is build on 1.56.1, so i am upgrading my runtime with my new substrate version in polkadot explorer by using my latest WASM,and then i got that error on my explorer

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise in what you are trying to do?

Comment: As my question says I am want to upgrade my chain to a latest version of substrate which  has also been answered in [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/runtime-upgrade-error-host-doesnt-provide-such-function-envext-storage-root), but was not able to it successfully and it also suggests that i need to upgrade my client but i was unable to find any documentation regarding that neither any relevant question here.

Comment: Added information to my answer again

Comment: Thank for your response..Its work