# How to update the client with new chain spec?

Tags: upgrade, client

By referring to this solution, it works properly unless there are modifications in the chain spec.

[How to upgrade the client?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/how-to-upgrade-the-client)

In my case, the chain spec file has been modified as I removed some pallets and also deleted related information about the removed pallets in the `chain_spec.rs` file and updated the new client code (`service.rs`).

I ran the upgrade with the new runtime, and it was successful. However, when updating the client for the RPC node, it fails due to a genesis mismatch between the old and new client

Do we have any ideas to address it without interrupting the chain?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to update the chain_spec file in your client, that is wrong.

The chain_spec defines your genesis block, and therefore it should never be updated. After the runtime upgrade, there is not action needed for the client (unless the new runtime enforces it, in which case you should have updated the client first).

You will only have to use the new chain_spec in case you want to run a fresh chain, for example a testnet with zombienet.

Comment: I have a pallet called `pallet_society `with a genesis value in version A. In version B, I remove the `pallet_society` from both the runtime and the GenesisConfig of `pallet-society` in `chain_spec.rs`. The runtime upgrade works fine, and the new client binary contains an updated chain spec. How do I handle future client updates when configuring a new service for the client, considering the updated chain spec?

Comment: I am attempting to update the client service with the modified chain spec beforehand, not trying to update the chain spec itself.

Comment: The chain_spec do not need to be updated for new clients. They still need to use the original chain_spec. `pallet-society` will be remove when the client sync with the blockchain.

Comment: yeah but new binary is incompatible with old chain spec

Comment: This is my error:
`Error: Service(Client(Storage("Error parsing spec file: unknown field `society`, expected one of...`