Unable to perform forkless upgrade: host function is not registered
We forked the parachain template of the Polkadot SDK with its dependencies tied to v1.7.1 (https://github.com/MandalaChain/Mandala-Node/blob/mainnet/Cargo.toml#L10) of the Polkadot SDK and we launched it a couple of months ago on mainnet.
After the launch, we made these improvements to the codebase:

added EVM pallet and related primvites
made the runtime EVM-compatible
implemented AccountID20
added async-backing on our testnet runtime (not mainnet)
updated its dependencies to v1.11.0
(https://github.com/MandalaChain/Mandala-Node/blob/main/Cargo.toml#L17)

Now we want to update the runtime via forkless upgrade while preserving the block history.
Following the tutorial here, we setup Zombienet to be able to test the upgrade locally.
Here is how we did it in details:

Launched the Zombienet with three validators (Alice, Bob, and Charlie) for Rococo, and one collator (with the current node version running on mainnet) for the parachain;
With the updated codebase, we built our newest binary;
After locating the compressed wasm (mandala_runtime.compressed.wasm) in /target/release/wbuild/mandala-runtime, we opened Polkadot.js Portal;
Went to Developer -> Extrinsics, use Sudo account (in this case Bob), select sudo -> sudoUncheckedWeight(call, weight);
Then uploaded mandala_runtime.compressed.wasm, leaving both of the weight parameters set to the default value of 0.

However, after a while we logged an error and then the chain bricked:

[Parachain] Cannot create a runtime error=Other("runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:ext_storage_proof_size_storage_proof_size_version_1'")
[Parachain] Failed to collect collation info. error=Application(VersionInvalid"Other error happened while constructing the runtime: runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env: ext_storage_p roof_size_storage_proof_size_version_1'"))
[Parachain] err="Unable to produce collation"
[Parachain] Cannot create a runtime error=Other"runtime requires function imports which are not pre sent on the host: 'env:ext_storage_proof_size_storage_proof_size_version_1'")
[Parachain] Unsupported Offchain Worker API version: (Err(Application(VersionInvalid("Other error ha ppened while constructing the runtime: runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env ext_sto rage_proof_size_storage_proof_size_version_1'"))), Err(Application(VersionInvalid"Other error happened while constructi ng the runtime: runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env: ext_storage_proof_size_storage proof_size_version_1'")))). Consider turning off offchain workers if they are not part of your runtime..

We found a similar issue here and implemented the solution, but after adding said HostFunctions on our ParachainClient, the chain is still halted.
Update: we also found this issue, so with our bricked chain, we restarted the node with the new binary (pointing to the same --base-path <PATH> as before to persist the storage). However, the chain is still bricked.
If there is any info missing, I'd be happy to add them here.
Any pointers is appreciated!

You are aware that you need to restart your node with the new binary if you make changes in the node right?

@Daan-R0GUE I think I know what you meant, just found this: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3008/674
Will try and give update.

Restarting the node doesn't change anything. I can see that no blocks being produced. Not sure what else to do tbh.

You have to be much more specific in what errors you are facing and it would also help how you are doing these upgrades. One thing that might increase the difficulty of the upgrade is whether you are upgrading your parachain to use async backing or not.

@Daan-R0GUE Thanks for the suggestion, I have added as much details as possible (keeping it brief but clear).

So you implemented the host functions but you get the same error? One thing I could advise is activate async backing separately from all the upgrades you are doing. There is too much what can go wrong by doing these upgrades in one go.

Also which runtime are you upgrading, testnet or mainnet?

@Daan-R0GUE Okay, I was also thinking of removing the async backing first just to test if the upgrade works. I'm upgrading only the mainnet runtime.
